# Функция возвращает значение, а что делать с ним дальше?

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой простой код)

```js
var calculateDelivery = function(necessity, region) {
  var regions = ['Луна', 'Крабовидная туманность', 'Галактика Туманность Андромеды', 'Туманность Ориона'];
  var sum;
  if (necessity === false) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (necessity === true) {
    switch (region) {
      case 'Луна':
        sum = 150;
        break;
      case 'Крабовидная туманность':
        sum = 250;
        break;
      case 'Галактика Туманность Андромеды':
        sum = 550;
        break;
      case 'Туманность Ориона':
        sum = 600;
        break;
    }
    if (regions.indexOf(region) != -1) {
      return 550;
    } else {
      return NaN;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

// Тут нужно посмотреть на возвращаемое значение и напечатать нужный текст
```

Совсем непонятно, как обратиться к значению в return и напечатать нужный текст, как подобное вообще пишется)

Если доставка нужна:
Стоимость доставки: 550 Q
Если результат функции 0:
Доставка не требуется
Если результат функции NaN:
Ошибка при расчете стоимости доставки

Comment: `console.log(calculateDelivery(true, 'Луна'));` - После всего кода.

Comment: @entithat в зависимости от return должен быть свой текст) если NaN - то выводится строка 'Ошибка при расчете стоимости' и тд

Comment: так сделать условие на нужный текст.. Результат функции Вы же получили уже..

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать например так :

```js
var calculateDelivery = function(necessity, region) {
  var regions = ['Луна', 'Крабовидная туманность', 'Галактика Туманность Андромеды', 'Туманность Ориона'];
  if (necessity === false) return 0;
  switch (region) {
    case 'Луна':
      return 150;
    case 'Крабовидная туманность':
      return 250;
    case 'Галактика Туманность Андромеды':
      return 550;
    case 'Туманность Ориона':
      return 600;
    default:
      return NaN;
  }
}

function func() {
  var a = document.getElementById('select').value;
  var result = calculateDelivery(true, a);
  var text = '';
  if (isNaN(result))
    text = 'Ошибка при расчете стоимости доставки';
  else if (+result === 0)
    text = 'Доставка не требуется';
  else
    text = `${result} Q`;

  document.getElementById('result').innerText = text;
}
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="Луна">Луна</option>
  <option value="Крабовидная туманность">Крабовидная туманность</option>
  <option value="Галактика Туманность Андромеды">Галактика Туманность Андромеды</option>
  <option value="Туманность Ориона">Туманность Ориона</option>
  <option value="Орион">Орион</option>
</select>
<button onclick="func();">calc</button>
<hr/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое) значит нужно было простое присвоение дополнительной переменной) я только учусь)

Comment: я и функцию вашу немного переписал, убрал лишнее(как мне показалось)

Answer (score 0):

> console.log(calculateDelivery(true, 'Луна')); - После всего кода.

Только чтобы увидеть результат, для этого надо открыть консоль браузера клавишей F12. Так же для наглядности можно воспользоваться alert(calculateDelivery(true, 'Луна')), но пользоваться alert - плохая практика.

```js
var calculateDelivery = function (necessity, region) {
  var regions = ['Луна', 'Крабовидная туманность', 'Галактика Туманность Андромеды', 'Туманность Ориона'];
  var sum;
  if (necessity === false) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (necessity === true ) {
    switch (region) {
  case 'Луна':
    sum = 150;
    alert('Стоимость доставки: ' + sum)
  break;
  case 'Крабовидная туманность':
    sum = 250;
    alert('Стоимость доставки: ' + sum)
  break;
  case 'Галактика Туманность Андромеды':
    sum = 550;
    alert('Стоимость доставки: ' + sum)
  break;
  case 'Туманность Ориона':
    sum = 600;
    alert('Стоимость доставки: ' + sum)
  break;
  }
    if (regions.indexOf(region) != -1 ) {
      return 550;
    }
    else {
      return NaN;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

calculateDelivery(true, 'Крабовидная туманность');
```